# slurm job status for an old already finished job

Tags: slurm

I want to see the status of one of my older jobs submitted using slurm. I have used sacct -j , but it does not give me information on exactly the date when the job was submitted/terminated etc. I want to check the date, time of the job submissio. I tried to use scontrol, but I suppose that only works for current running/pending jobs not for older jobs which are already finished. It will be great if someone could suggest me a slurm command for checking the job status along with job submission date and time etc for an already finished old job. Thanks in advance

Comment: sacct is the correct command but it assumes accounting is properly configured, notably `slurmdbd`

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As you mentioned that `sacct -j` is working but not providing the proper information, I'll assume that accounting is properly set and working.

You can select the output of the `sacct` command with the `-o` flag, so to get exactly what you want you can use:

`sacct -j JOBID -o jobid,submit,start,end,state`

You can use `sacct --helpformat` to get the list of all the available fields for the output.

Comment: thank you very much @Carles , it really solved my problem, now I got information about everything I needed.

Comment: If the answer is right, please accept the answer as valid